# c++ vector iterator to function template

Tags: c++, vector, stl, iterator, parameter-passing

I'm new to STL. I'm trying to write a routine taking vector iterators as parameters. Namely, I need to pass vector.begin() and vector.end(). Can't figure why my code is not working:

```
template<typename T, typename Iter> void VectorQuickSort(Iter itL, Iter itR){
    const int nSize = (itR - itL);
    if(nSize<2) return;
    Iter iBeginning(itL), iEnd(itR);
    --itR;
    T tPivot = *( itL + (nSize/2) );
    while( itL <= itR ){
        while( *itL < tPivot ) ++itL;
        while( *itR > tPivot ) --itR;
        if( itL <= itR ){
            std::iter_swap(itL,itR);
            ++itL;
            --itR;
        }
   }
   VectorQuickSort(iBeginning,itR);
   VectorQuickSort(itL,iEnd);
}
```

And in `main()` I simply call `VectorQuickSort(vInput.begin(),vInput.end());`. Compiler tells me `error: no instance of function template "VectorQuickSort" matches the argument list`. Any help appreciated :)

EDIT: As a warning for someone potentially trying to use the code above: even if you apply the answer provided, there is still something wrong with the sorting algo itself. I fail to translate properly working C version into STL style.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can't deduce the template parameter `T` from those arguments. In fact, you don't even need `T`. It is redundant because you can work out the type of `T` from `Iter` - after all, the iterator iterates over elements of type `T`. Change it to just this:

```
template<typename Iter>
```

Then, if you're using C++11, you can change the line that uses `T` to automatically deduce the type of `tPivot`:

```
auto tPivot = *( itL + (nSize/2) );
```

If you don't have C++11 support, you can instead use [`std::iterator_traits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_traits) to determine the appropriate type:

```
typename std::iterator_traits<Iter>::value_type tPivot = *( itL + (nSize/2) );
```

You can perhaps simplify this with a `typedef`:

```
typedef typename std::iterator_traits<Iter>::value_type value_type;
value_type tPivot = *( itL + (nSize/2) );
```

Comment: +1 (and I wish I could +1 this again for saving me the time to write up pretty-much verbatim what I was about to embark on). Honestly he doesn't even need to "know" the type if this is done succinctly enough. Example can be [found here](http://ideone.com/BNMEjg)

Answer (score 0):

You need to write `VectorQuickSort<int,/*iterator type*/>(vInput.begin(),vInput.end());` or whatever you'd like it to be templated above, notice you mention it's templated over T but the function has no way to deduce where/how T is templated...
Either delete T and use auto or tell the function how is T templated